# Is there a pluggable tree app for Django with a good admin?

Tags: django, tree

Or asked the other way: is there a good pluggable admin for any existing tree apps?

I've been trying to find a good way to handle hierarchal data in a Django app. django-mptt and django-treebeard both seem to work well enough for the infrastructure, but the admin options I've found are either broken, don't allow any sort of easy reordering or depend on installing a large external CMS.

All I want is an admin list view that shows the hierarchy and allows some sort of reordering (drag n drop optional, I'll settle for up/down arrows!).

Answer (score 2):

This is the FeinCMS tree admin functionality pulled out into a pluggable app:

https://github.com/piquadrat/django-treeadmin

Answer (score 0):

You can use Feincms functionality for display trees (by mptt) in admin. 
more you can find in this article 
http://www.michelepasin.org/blog/2009/08/18/django-admin-and-mptt-2/